# Convert.FromBase64String gives the error of "The input is not a valid Base-64 string"

Tags: c#, base64, character, converters, .net-6.0

This is my string which i try to convert it from base64 to a humanly possible readable string:

```
eyJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy54bWxzb2FwLm9yZy93cy8yMDA1LzA1L2lkZW50aXR5L2NsYWltcy9kYXRlb2ZiaXJ0aCI6IjIvMjUvMTk5MSAxMjowMDowMCBBTSIsIm5iZiI6MTY0MTQwNjk2MCwiZXhwIjoxNjQxNDEwNTYwLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo3MDAwLyIsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjcwMDAvIn0
```

It works on the online sites of converting from base64 like [this site](https://www.base64decode.org/)

On c# .net6 i try this code:

```
var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64payload);
```

which base64payload is that above string.
Why do i get this error on c# dotnet 6?

```
"The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters."
```

as far as i know,( a-z A-Z 0-9 / +) are valid and my eyes dont see any false base64 characters in this string + it works on elsewhere.

Comment: You're getting the error because it's not valid. The length is not evenly divisible by 4. It's missing a padding character. What produced it?

Comment: I tried to splite a token middle claim section manually.
 var accessToken = context.AccessToken;
                var base64payload = accessToken.Split('.')[1];
which access token is an actual token .

Comment: That's not what *produced* it. It's just conveying the value to you.

Comment: when i add a = at the end, it works! is that the problem?

Comment: The site you linked is taking liberties with the decoding. It's ignoring the fact that you don't have the correct padding. For strictly correct Base64 encoding, it requires the padding. Whatever produced it is removing the padding. There's an implicit contract between you and the producer that the padding is assumed, but that requires you to add it before you can use it with something that *doesn't* conform to that contract, such as a strict decoder like `Convert.FromBase64String()`.

Comment: The string is the payload part of a JWT. A JWT uses Base64Url encoding. Base64Url usually works without padding and many base64 decoders are quite tolerant regarding padding. The .NET Base64 decoder is known to be strict.

Comment: Wow thank you so much !

Comment: funny thing is that i copied the code from a youtube tutorial video that works in front of my eyes yet not working for me, the only difference is that the youtuber uses previous versions of .net !

Comment: Um, no, previous versions of .NET did not behave differently in this regard. `Convert.FromBase64String` has always been strict about padding. Something else is different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your string is missing some padding. You can check for that [here](https://base64.guru/tools/) and repair it if you want to.

The repaired and correct string is:

```
eyJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy54bWxzb2FwLm9yZy93cy8yMDA1LzA1L2lkZW50aXR5L2NsYWltcy9kYXRlb2ZiaXJ0aCI6IjIvMjUvMTk5MSAxMjowMDowMCBBTSIsIm5iZiI6MTY0MTQwNjk2MCwiZXhwIjoxNjQxNDEwNTYwLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo3MDAwLyIsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjcwMDAvIn0=
```

After, use the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var coded = ("eyJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy54bWxzb2FwLm9yZy93cy8yMDA1LzA1L2lkZW50aXR5L2NsYWltcy9kYXRlb2ZiaXJ0aCI6IjIvMjUvMTk5MSAxMjowMDowMCBBTSIsIm5iZiI6MTY0MTQwNjk2MCwiZXhwIjoxNjQxNDEwNTYwLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo3MDAwLyIsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjcwMDAvIn0=");
            string inputStr = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(coded));
            Console.WriteLine(inputStr);

        }
    }
```